# Source of Golan Trevize's intuition

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

I've just read Isaac Asimov's Foundation series and in his novels Asimov always explains odd character traits but I haven't found it for Golan Trevize. Why is his intuition so reliable? Did I miss something in the books, has the author said it outside of the books?

Comment: I think *Foundation's Triumph* has a little on it, but not much.

Comment: *"Intuition is the art, peculiar to the human mind, of working out the correct answer from data that is, in itself, incomplete or even, perhaps, misleading."* - Isaac Asimov

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the source and nature of Treviz's talent is never revealed or commented upon.

Comment: That's not strictly true, it *is* stated that some of his thought process is invisible to those with mental powers. Can't remember the exact quote but I believe Munn Li Compor describes his thoughts as sometimes going somewhere he can't follow. There is something different about his brain.

Answer (score 0):

The source of Trevize's intuition is not revealed. However, the reason for his intuition. In Foundation and Earth, Asimov discusses how the metaphysical relationship between intuition, the three fundamental laws and the larger universe.

Comment: Do you have a quote for that?

Comment: Yes, please quote or at least paraphrase the discussion. I understand the reason why Treviz was chosen for the task but not why and/or how he has the crucial trait, the above average intuition. For instance there was a character with above average ability to trace ship through hyperspace, Munn Li Compor I think, nobody (from first Foundation) suspected  anything but Asimov explained in great detail how he had limited telepathy. And similarly I found author's explanation for all other odd characters. Except Golan Treviz.

Answer (score -2):

It is a one in a really realy big nuber chance such a person is born whose intuition is always correct, he is that person. Born with the perfect intuition. Because of the size of the galaxy there is a possibility such a person could be born into the world.

Comment: Is there any evidence that this is *Asimov's* explanation?